# Ajax authentication with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm able to recieve the requested xml with

```
curl -X GET -u username:password url
```

but not with

```
$.get('url',
        {username:"username",password:"password"},
        function (data) {


        });
```

No javascript errors, no cross domain policy issues.
It might be a syntax error but I failed to find a decent tutorial yet.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Basic Auth and Jquery and Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: @fotis can you explain about the curl command ? is it in any browser ? shoudl i download something ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It's a [php command](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) but you can run it on a linux terminal.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you'd need the plain format :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'json',
    //whatever you need
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(user, password));
    },
    success: function () {});
});

function make_base_auth(user, password) {
    var tok = user + ':' + password;
    var hash = btoa(tok);
    return 'Basic ' + hash;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be password instead of pass in the function

Comment: @Royi Namir, there's an extra space after `Authorization`, which fails setting the header.

Comment: why am I getting stack overflow with this solution? :) What could I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `beforeSend`you could use the `headers` property to add the `authorization` header.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": make_base_auth(user, password)
    }
    success: function () {});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the other answer, you should be using beforeSend function of Jquery Ajax to add authorization header

```
function setAuthHeader(xhr){
            var creds = username + ':' + password;
            var basicScheme = btoa(creds);
            var hashStr = "Basic "+basicScheme;
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', hashStr);
    }

  $.get('url',
         beforeSend: setAuthHeader,
        function (data) {


     });
```

Comment: if it was pointed out in the other answer - why not upvote that one instead of adding the same answer ?!?!