# No results from JSON API GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am trying to query the Reed jobs site to return Construction based jobs in Sheffield.

I have tried literally everything I can think of and posted numerous posts on here to try and get the code to work but to no avail.

Can someone please try the code themselves and see if they can work it out?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

````
<script>
$(function (){

  var $jobs = $('#jobs');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    username: '5afe0f90-3480-4d47-8206-3529815a610a',
    password: '',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=construction&location=sheffield',
    success: function(jobs) {
      $.each(jobs, function(i, job){
        $jobs.append('<li>my job</li>')
      });
    },
    error: (err)=> {alert(err)}
  });

});
</script>

<ul id="jobs"></ul>```
````

Comment: Use the network tab in chrome dev tools to analyze the request.

Comment: doesnt this line  $jobs.append('<li>my job</li>') should be  $jobs.append('<li>' + job +'</li>')

Comment: Assuming this isn't a CORS problem, then you most likely need to encrypt the username/password and include it in the request as a basic authentication header. Check the documentation.

Comment: use https instead of http. and check your network tab to see the status.

Comment: you can try remove username and password, and add the following instead:
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('5afe0f90-3480-4d47-8206-3529815a610a:' ));
  },

Comment: @SuleymanSah I have implemented your solution but still no luck. I have created a CodePen example.

https://codepen.io/FluxedDigital/pen/oNNNBbx

Comment: This api really seems to very difficult to call :(

Comment: @SuleymanSah I know :( I don't know if its any help but here is the documentation!

https://www.reed.co.uk/developers/Jobseeker

Comment: @SuleymanSah the request works in post man which is strange

Comment: @SuleymanSah I just get this error alert now `[object Object]`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have, but can can't see anything. The request works fine in PostMan https://www.reed.co.uk/developers/Jobseeker

Comment: The important part is right at the bottom: `Important:
You will need to include your api key for all requests in a basic authentication http header as the username, leaving the password empty.`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have included the username in the script

Comment: I don't believe that's quite the same as a basic authentication header. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10226395/519413

Comment: I could called the api within nodejs, but no luck within vanilla javascript.